# Create directory on add blog to a Wordpress-multisite

Tags: php, blogs, wordpress

I have a wordpress multisite plugin.I want to add a folder(foldername=domainname) when a new blog is added to the wordpress multisite network.
Also the folder must be renamed if the domain name changes...

Is there any hook for this?

My plugin is a wp-mvc multisite plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to do something like this:

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```